# Proxy setting of domain user though command line

Tags: proxy

I have to access proxy server as a domain user, so in the proxy setting of /etc/environment I have to write my user name after the domain name i.e domainname\username (Ex: AAAA\abc) but when it executes it is showing like AAAAabc. It means "" is considered and changed the username as a result proxy server doesn't validate that user.
Please help me how can I configure proxy in such a situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the 3 types of shell quoting should work, ex.:

```
$ var=aaaa\ABC ; echo "$var"
aaaaABC
```

but

```
$ var=aaaa\\ABC ; echo "$var"
aaaa\ABC

$ var="aaaa\ABC" ; echo "$var"
aaaa\ABC

$ var='aaaa\ABC' ; echo "$var"
aaaa\ABC
```